# Pruning the package tree with apt-get and yum

Tags: package-management, apt, yum, dependencies

I love the Macports and Arch package managers, because I can generate a listing of all of the packages that I have manually installed, and "prune" the package tree every once in a while to keep my distribution lean. I would like to know how I can do this using `apt-get` and `yum`.

For example, with Macports, I can type `port echo requested` and get a nice listing of all of the packages that I have explicitly installed. If I see a package I installed a few weeks ago that I no longer need, I can immediately uninstall it. To get rid of unused dependencies, I can repeatedly execute `port uninstall leaves`. Analogous commands are available using `pacman`.

It is not clear to me how I can achieve similar functionality using `apt-get` and `yum` after reading the relevant man pages and doing a fair amount of Googling. One of the most important functions of a good package manager should be to let the administrator easily manage the list of explicitly installed packages. Certainly I am missing something.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Linking this related question for Ubuntu / apt: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show packages that were manually installed, use
`apt-mark showmanual`. To show packages that were automatically installed, use `apt-mark showauto`.

Also, `apt-get` has `autoremove`. From the man page

> autoremove
>
> autoremove is used to remove packages
>   that were automatically installed to
>   satisfy dependencies for other packages and
>   are now no longer needed.

So use `apt-get autoremove` for this.

Generally `apt` will prompt you if packages are available to be autoremoved, so I would expect a user to become aware of this command quite quickly.

Additionally, there are packages like `debfoster` and `deborphan` to help users to reduce package clutter.

Also `wajig` has several commands that can be used to prune packages, including, but not limited to `large`, and `sizes`, which can be used to look at the large packages installed on the system.

Also, it is worth mentioning the `apt` log files in `/var/log/apt`, notably `history.log`, which keep a log of the installations and removals performed by `apt`.

Comment: How can I list the packages that I have explicitly installed? My question isn't about how I can clean unused dependencies; it's about how I can remove packages that I explicitly installed earlier but no longer need.

Comment: @void-pointer `apt-mark showmanual`
`

Answer (score 2):

yum has many ways:

```
yum autoremove
yumdb search reason user (this will include things done via. the installer though).
yum history
yum list distro-extras
yum list extras
package-cleanup --leaves (see man page for options).
```

...the main difference to understand is that with Mac ports the software you are using is just controlling a tiny subset of packages, whereas with yum/apt you'll be dealing with the entire system.